# Writing Elasticsearch logs from Docker to an external volume

Tags: docker, elastic-stack

I have an ELK Docker installed that made the HDD explode with 0 space available.
I looked everywhere in the documentation and this is the best I could find:

```
sudo docker run -p 5601:5601 -p 9200:9200  -p 5044:5044 \
-v elk-data:/var/lib/elasticsearch --name elk sebp/elk
```

However, this just tells the Docker where to write the logs INSIDE the container and not outside where I mounted a large hard drive.

What did I miss?

Comment: What do you mean by `just tells the Docker where to write the logs INSIDE the container`? If you mount a host directory to the container volume, the data wrote to the volume does goes outside of the container.

Comment: I thought so but when running "fdisk -l" it returns an empty list for some reason. I'm not able to see it.

Comment: What system are you running the Docker host on? Are you using docker-machine?

Comment: It's a Ubuntu 16.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`elk-data` is a named volume, which should be defined through:

`$ docker volume create elk-data`

That will create the volume inside `/var/lib/docker/volumes`

You should perhaps, instead, use:

`$ docker run -v /local/path/to/big/disk:/var/lib/elasticsearch -p 5601:5601 -p 9200:9200  -p 5044:5044 --name elk sebp/elk`

If you really want to use a named volume, you can create one using the bind syntax:

`$ docker volume create --name elk-data \
--opt type=none \
--opt device=/local/path/to/big/disk \
--opt o=bind`

Comment: just for the record, /local/path/to/big/disk = path on the HOST itself, correct?

Comment: Yes, it is. It's "semi" documented here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/#driver-specific-options

Comment: I'm very new to dockers and that "docker volume create" command is really all it took. Cheers for the help.

Comment: No problem. It's not documented very well, as most will use `-v host:container` syntax. But  volumes are just local mount commands and all the options work :)